# Cycle criteria of fractional linear functions

Tags: functions, reference-request, functional-equations

I have just read a [paper](https://ichoosemath.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/finalest-flf.pdf) about fractional linear functions written by Justin Lanier. I have tried to prove some observations he left in page 13. Here is the statement I want to prove:

> Given function $f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ ,then
>
> $$f^{\circ n}(x)=x \iff \frac{a+d}{2\sqrt{ad-bc}}=\cos(\frac{k\pi}{n}), 1\leq k\leq n-1$$
>
> The cycle period is $\gcd(k,n)$

$f^{\circ n}(x)$ denotes $n$-th iterate of function $f(x)$

I will sketch my proof here: $f^{\circ n}(x)=\frac{A_nx+B_n}{C_nx+D_n}$ and the following system is satisfied:
$$
\begin{cases}
R_n=\frac{A_n-D_n}{a-d}\\
A_{n+1}=aA_n+bcR_n\\
D_{n+1}=dD_n+bcR_n\\
B_n=bR_n\\
C_n=cR_n\\
A_0=B_0=1
\end{cases}
$$

thus $f^{\circ n}(x)=x\iff R_n=0$. Sequences $A_n,B_n$ satisfy a system of linear recurrence relations, so with the help of Linear algebra, the closed form of $R_n$ is:

$$R_n=\frac{\lambda_1^n-\lambda_2^n}{\lambda_1-\lambda_2} $$
$\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are 2 roots of the equation $\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda+(ad-bc)=0$. It is certain that equation $R_n=0$ yields the result.

What I want to know:

1. Is my idea correct? Honestly, I'm worried that the statement is not complete. I checked a lot of cases and the computation seems to agree.
2. If you know any other papers writing about this problem, please let me know. I couldn't find them.

Comment: I don't understand; the paper referenced seems to be working over a finite field, and given that you write $\sqrt{}$ and $\cos$ you seem to be working over $\mathbb{C}$ or whatever. If you do want to work over $\mathbb{C}$ then it probably helps to know that every element of order diving $n$ is similar to $x\mapsto\zeta^k x$ (with $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/n}$), and that your criterion can be expressed in terms of the invariants $\text{tr}(A)$, $\det(A)$.

Comment: You are right. It seems like I overcomplicated things. It is a lot nicer to deal with the equation $A^n=I$.